# Change a django form field's value after validation

Tags: django, django-forms, faceted-search

I am developing a faceted search system. Below the search box, there's a radio select widget that has the options:

```
O New search     O Within your results
```

When the page is loaded, new search should be selected by default, so I'm using the `initial` keyword for that.

The problem I have is that after a user selects `New search` and places a query, I want the default to be switched to `Within your results`, since most searches are refinements.

So what I need to do is change the value the user submitted, which is stored in a Django `Form`.

How can I change the value of the form field? Validation has already occurred, and from what I have gathered so far, `request.GET` is immutable (probably a good thing), and I can't change the `Form` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea, instead of hacking the user input you could show that field only when you have a query parameter for the search.

This way the first time the user 'hit' the view he doesn't see the useless radio field.

e.g. here I would use the searching param during the __init__ of the form to set the field as hidden and with the right initial value ( you can also do something like DrTysa suggested and move the searching detection at form level looking at the data dict)

```
searching = False
if data.get('query'):
    searching = True
form = SearchForm(data, searching=searching)
```

Comment: This is more or less the route I'm taking. I forgot that the radio buttons shouldn't be shown initially. I'm not dealing with the hidden form though - if it's blank, I can imply that the user wants a new search.

Answer (score 1):

The django recommended way to modify `request.GET` is to [call the `copy` method.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.copy)

```
mutable_get = request.GET.copy()
mutable_get['search'] = 'within_results'
```

You could also set the initial dynamically in the form `__init__` or just by accessing the bound form field attributes.

```
form.fields['my_field'].initial = True
```

Which one works will depend on how you're building the forms.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'do_search' in data: # or any other way to find out if there is an existing search
            kwargs['initial'] = kwargs.setdefault('initial', {'your_radio': 'your_within_value'})
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
```